# Creating a shortcode, but getting tied up with OOP and Classes?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, oop

I have tried creating a new class that holds an action which creates a shortcode and the shortcode is on my site but doesn't appear to be working. Can anyone tell me where I appear to be going wrong please?

The class is written in it's own PHP file located at site_URL/includes/frontend.registration-form.php

Dreamweaver isn't throwing any syntax errors?

```
    <?php



class RegistrationForm {

    function __construct (){
        $this->make_shortcode();
    }

    function make_shortcode (){
        add_shortcode ('Show Form', array($this, 'form_generate'));
    }

    function form_generate () {

        ob_start(); ?>

            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Form Name</legend>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Email Address</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwordinput">Password</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Store Name</label>  
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Store Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                  </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>

    <?php $output = ob_clean();
    return ($output);

    }

} /*END OF CLASS*/

$new_form = new RegistrationForm;
return ($new_form);

?>
```

Comment: Is it included, initialized? E.g. via functions.php, because just putting it in a folder won't do it.

Comment: How do I initialize it? would that be a require_once call in the child theme functions.php file?

Comment: That would work for example. Or you make it a plugin, but that's a whole other topic.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see any issue with the OOP code that would cause it not to work.

I think the problem is with the shortcode itself. I don’t believe shortcodes can have spaces. `Show Form` is not a valid shortcode name. `[Show Form]` would be parsed as as a shortcode named `Show` with an attribute `Form`.

The conventional format for this shortcode would be `show_form`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I've updated that now but it still doesn't appear to make a difference. Do I have to require_once the class file anywhere as the php file with the class code is in a sub folder of the child theme? I appreciate that some of this functionality might be better loaded as a plugin but I wanted to try building it into a theme first. Thanks

Comment: [Shortcode API – Formal Syntax – Names](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Names), just to elaborate.

Comment: You do need to include it into your functions file, yes. The only PHP file WordPress will load automatically is functions.php.